# Microsoft ACE OleDB : Could not find file on release version

Tags: asp.net, oledb, aceoledb

I am reading `.dbf` files using Microsoft ACE OLEDB. I always get the following error when I try to release the application:

> path name : could not find file.

However, the process works on the local version. Here is my connection string:

```
Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\"\\\\Sv050r03c01dcp1\\Public\\Groupes\\Dbmgs\\Applications légères\\FiMun\\Données\";Extended Properties=dBase VI;
```

The permissions on the folder have already been verified. It is server side, can someone give me things to verify on the server?

Answer (score 0):

According to [ConnectionString.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/dbf-foxpro/) the connection string for the `ACE.OLEDB` should be in the following format,

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\folder;
Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;
```

Also, I am not sure if it's a typo but your connection-string's `Extended Properties` should be `IV`, not `VI`. The versions I have heard of are dBase II, dBase III, dBase IV, and dBase 5.